# BeautifulSoup(html) not working, saying can't call module?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import urllib2
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup        # html
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup     # xml
import BeautifulSoup                # everything
import re


f = o.open( 'http://www.google.com', p)
html = f.read()
f.close()


soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

**Getting an error saying the line with soup = BeautifulSoup(html) says 'module' object is not callable.**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your `import BeautifulSoup` makes `BeautifulSoup` refer to the module, not the class as it did after `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`. If you're going to import the whole module, you might want to omit the `from ...` line or perhaps rename the class afterward:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 
Soup = BeautifulSoup
...
import BeautifulSoup
....
soup = Soup(html)
```

Answer (score 6):

@Blair's answer has the right slant but I'd perform some things slightly differently, i.e.:

```
import BeautifulSoup
Soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup
```

(recommended), or

```
import BeautifulSoup
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as Soup
```

(not bad either).

Answer (score -1):

**Install BeautifulSoup4**
sudo easy_install BeautifulSoup4

**Recommendation**
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: This answer makes a lot of assumptions: how do we know we're on a Linux machine with "easy_install" available? How do we know it's not already installed? Plus, thin question was asked three years ago...