# Python / parsing: BeautifulSoup error "module obj is not callable" with results from Mechanize

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

BeautifulSoup and me are not recognizing the results of a `br.response().read()`.
I've imported BeautifulSoup

```
#snippet:
# Select the first (index zero) form
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
br['__EVENTTARGET'] = list_of_dates[0]
br['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = 'calMain'
br['__VIEWSTATE'] = viewstate
br['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = eventvalidation

response = br.submit()
print br.response().read() #*#this prints the html I'm expecting*

soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read()) #*#but this throws 
#TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.  
#Yet if I call soup = BeautifulSoup("http://page.com"), it's cool.*

selecttable = soup.find('table',{'id':"tblItems"})
#/snippet
```

... and so on

So I grok I have the wrong kind of "object", but, what kind of "object" does BeautifulSoup want?

Comment: What import statement are you using to import beautiful soup?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368231/beautifulsouphtml-not-working-saying-cant-call-module

Comment: your updated script again does br.response.read() twice. You need to call `BeautifulSoup(raw)`.  you should just call response.read once.  Also, you probably shouldn't be calling the module object and instead should be calling it on the response object.

Comment: So I've cut "cooked" altogether and now call BeautifulSoup(raw). Now to test this with some non-dummy data.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

Instead of

```
import BeautifulSoup
```

Otherwise I think you are doing the right thing!

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
response = br.submit()
print br.response().read() #*#this prints the html I'm expecting*

soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response().read())
```

Why don't you try:

```
response = br.submit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read())
```

I suspect it has to do with the fact that you're calling `.read()` on `br.response()`, when in my history of using mechanize, I've always saved `response()` to a variable and called `.read()` from there.  I don't know it will work, and it doesn't quite explain why `print br.response().read()` works, but give it a shot.

Alternatively, BeautifulSoup's HTML parser may not like what mechanize is feeding it.  You could try using [a different parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

Comment: agreed on both your points + specifying a parser might help too.

Answer (score 0):

Just confirm that your import is like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

or for BeautifulSoup4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried only reading the object once and then saving the result.

For example:

```
raw = br.response().read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(raw)
```

With file objects, you can read them once and then have to reopen them to read again.  It looks like you are reading them twice.  The other thing you should do is print the type signature of br.response before and after reading.

To make it easier to debug, try printing type signatures:

```
print type(response) # see the type of response from above
raw = br.response().read()
print type(raw)
print type(br.response().read()) # see what happens the second time :P
```

Also, it would help if you posted the stack trace too.